# Calcular la hora exacta de dos fechas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que quiero lograr es tener el tiempo de dos fechas pero ala hora de hacer un update de las dos fechas y así obtener el día, hora, minutos, segundos y se ejecuta bien pero la hora no es exacta ya que me aumenta siempre +1h.

```
 2022-05-17 09:32:30.000 // de tipo datetime
 2022-05-18 13:13:45.000 // de tipo datetime

 y me da como resultado:

 1:4:41:15

 y debe de ser:

 1:3:41:15

UPDATE Tabla1 SET  Dias= DATEDIFF(DAY, FechaE, FechaS) ,Horas= DATEDIFF (HOUR,FechaE, FechaS)%24, Minutos=  DATEDIFF (minute, FechaE, Fechas)% 60, Segundos= DATEDIFF (second, FechaE, Fechas)%60
```

Comment: que tal con 59? no se la verdad pero algo en relacion al calculo quizas sea el problema

Comment: tambien pienso lo mismo pero no le encuentro el por que me redondea

Comment: revisa el formato tambien de la fecha y hor, esos 000 al final esan demas creo yo...

Comment: No debería de afectar además lo pone el tipo de dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que DATEDIFF() no hace el cálculo de diferencia de secciones de tiempo completo, sino que calcula la cantidad de saltos. Por ejemplo: `DATEDIFF(YEAR,'20211231 23:59:59', '20220101 00:00:00')` genera el mismo resultado que `DATEDIFF(YEAR,'20210101 00:00:00', '20220101 23:59:59')`. Aunque en uno haya diferencia de casi dos años y en otro de solo un segundo.

Para solucionar esto, se puede utilizar una medida inferior para obtener un cálculo más certero.

```
SELECT Dias     =  DATEDIFF(SECOND, FechaE, FechaS) / (3600*24),
       Horas    = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, FechaE, FechaS) / 3600) %24, 
       Minutos  = (DATEDIFF(SECOND, FechaE, Fechas) / 60  ) % 60, 
       Segundos = (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, FechaE, Fechas) / 1000) % 60 ,
       Cadena   = CONCAT( DATEDIFF( DAY, 0, DATEADD( MS, DATEDIFF( MS, FechaE, FechaS), 0)), ':', 
                          CONVERT( char(8), DATEADD( MS, DATEDIFF( MS, FechaE, FechaS), 0), 8))
FROM (VALUES( '2022-05-17T09:32:30.000', '2022-05-18T13:13:45.000'))x(FechaE, FechaS)
```

Edición: Agregué una forma adicional de obtener todo en una sola cadena.

Comment: haaa ok.
Gracias ya lo probé y funciono.

Comment: Edición: Agregué una forma adicional de obtener todo en una sola cadena.